# R Plotly: how to order pie chart?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm using the `plotly` package in R to build an R Shiny dashboard. I want to order my pie chart in a custom order (non-alphabetic, non-descending/ascending order). For some reason I can't find how to achieve this.

Help would be highly appreciated!

```
# Get Manufacturer
mtcars$manuf <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)

df <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(manuf) %>%
  summarize(count = n())

# Create custom order
customOrder <- c(df$manuf[12:22],df$manuf[1:11])

# Order data frame
df <- df %>% slice(match(customOrder, manuf))

# Create factor
df$manuf <- factor(df$manuf, levels = df[["manuf"]])

# Plot
df %>% plot_ly(labels = ~manuf, values = ~count) %>%
  add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout(title = "Donut charts using Plotly",  showlegend = F,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

Comment: can you give us a definition for `data`?

Comment: Thx @Joy. Changed the code a bit, should have been df.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, the answer is apparently twofold. Firstly, there is an argument in `plot_ly`, asking to sort the data on values (default is `TRUE`) or work with the custom order. Change this to `FALSE`.

Then, secondly, the order (clockwise) is different from the order in the data frame. The pie starts in the top right corner, and continues counterclockwise.

Hence, the following solves the problem:

```
# Get Manufacturer
mtcars$manuf <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)

df <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(manuf) %>%
  summarize(count = n())

# Create custom order
customOrder <- c(df$manuf[12:22],df$manuf[1:11])

# Adjust customOrder to deal with pie
customOrder <- c(customOrder[1],rev(customOrder[2:length(customOrder)]))

# Order data frame
df <- df %>% slice(match(customOrder, manuf))

# Create factor
df$manuf <- factor(df$manuf, levels = df[["manuf"]])

# Plot
df %>% plot_ly(labels = ~manuf, values = ~count, sort = FALSE) %>%
  add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout(title = "Donut charts using Plotly",  showlegend = F,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

Comment: Adding parameter sort = FALSE works in my case. Thanks.